# How to use \ in a string and check for it in a switch statement

Tags: javascript

```js
case "/" || "|" || "\":
    $(".slash").css("background-color", "#088a5a");
    break;
```

How to check for the backslash (\) character?

Comment: Read documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch That is not how to match multiple items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues: that's not how multiple cases work, and you need to escape the \

```js
case "/":
case "|":
case "\\":
    $(".slash").css("background-color", "#088a5a");
    break;
```

without a `break` statement (or `return` technically as well), the code will continue on.